# Force logout user after 24 hours Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, logout

I have an app and I have implemented Spring Security. Now I want to force logout a user 24 hrs after his login regardless of his activity. How can I achieve this?

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException 
    {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
        response.sendRedirect("/successfullLogin");
    }
}
```

The `setMaxInactiveInterval` is only for timing out session in case of inactivity.

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/loginPage**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
              .antMatchers("/guest/*").hasRole("GUEST")
              .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()  
              .and()
              .logout()
                 .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
              .and()
              .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/loginPage")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureUrl("/loginPage?error=true")
              .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/forbiddenPage")
              .and().csrf().disable();
```

This is my spring security configure method.

Comment: And what is logging out more than a session timeout?

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't understand your question. I want to logout the user forcefully after 24 hours of login.

Comment: And how is your logout different from only doing a session timeout? WHat makes you thing it does more.

Comment: So setMaxInactiveInterval logs out a user after 24 hrs of inactivity. So if the user sends a request after say 23 hrs of login he won't be logged out after 24 hrs from first login. I want to log the user out after 24 hrs from first login.

Comment: That isn't what you expressed in your question, so you might want to clarify that. Use the Spring Security session management and write a scheduler that removes those that are older then 24hrs.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did mention that logout the user regardless of his activity. Also I'm new to Spring Security, can you please tell me how do I get all active sessions and how do I check for how much time these sessions have been active. I tried looking for the last part quite a lot, but did not find an answer.

Comment: As i stated, use the Spring Security Session Management (which is not the same as Spring Session!), store the state in a db and then there is a column indicating when the session started.

Comment: @M.Deinum This method seems a bit too hacky, isn't there some API in spring security which allows us to setMaxInterval of a session.

Comment: No. As logging out and session inactivity (in your case as you described) are different.

Comment: no its not "too hacky" thats how you manage sessions. A server needs to know who are logged in, to keep track of that they need a database.

Comment: the only property that exists is `server.servlet.session.timeout` but that will get refreshed if the user keeps being active.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I thought Spring Security took care of that for me. Thanks for the answer.